# MPI_Reduce C/C++ - Signal: Segmentation Fault (11)

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, reduction

I don't understand well how the `MPI_Reduce` works with array.
I need to do an element wise sum.

To test the `MPI_Reduce` function I wrote this simple code and it works:

```
double a[4] = {0,1,2,(double)process_id};
double b[4];
MPI_Reduce(&a, &b, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(id == p-1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%f, ", b[i]);
    }
}
```

it prints this:

```
0.00000, 4.00000, 8.00000, 6.00000
```

when I run this code with 4 process. It works!

Now I implement my problem. Assuming I use `p` process, I need to reduce `p` matrices of dimensions `m * n` so I rewrite each matrices in form of array

```
double *a;
double **A;

A = new double*[n];
//code that compute matrix A
a = (double *) malloc(m * n * sizeof(double));
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        a[k] = A[i][j];
        k++;
    }
}
```

In this way I have the matrices that I need to reduce in form of array. Now I execute this reduction:

```
if(id == p-1){
    reduce_storage = (double *) malloc(m * n * sizeof(double));
}

MPI_Reduce(&a, &reduce_storage, m * n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Array *a* and *reduce_storage* are allocated in the same way so the are of the same dimension m * n, the value of *count* argument of MPI_Reduce. I don't understand why I try to run it return this error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
[EdoardoPC:01104] *** Process received signal ***
[EdoardoPC:01104] Signal: Aborted (6)
[EdoardoPC:01104] Signal code:  (-6)
[EdoardoPC:01104] *** Process received signal ***
[EdoardoPC:01104] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[EdoardoPC:01104] Signal code:  (128)
[EdoardoPC:01104] Failing at address: (nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand well how the MPI_Reduce works with array. I need to
> do an element wise sum.

From [source](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) about MPI_Reduce one can read:

> Reduces values on all processes to a single value
>
> int MPI_Reduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
> MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, int root, MPI_Comm comm)

In your case `MPI_Reduce` will work as the following image:

[image]

(image taken from https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/)

From the same source one can read:

> MPI_Reduce takes an array of input elements on each process and
> returns an array of output elements to the root process. The output
> elements contain the reduced result.

Now let look at your problem

> To test the MPI_Reduce function I write this simple code and it works:

```
double a[4] = {0,1,2,(double)process_id};
double b[4];
MPI_Reduce(&a, &b, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

All the parameter are correct; `&a` and `&b` match `const void *sendbuf` and `void *recvbuf`, respectively. The same applies to remaining parameters, namely `int`, `MPI_Datatype`, `MPI_Op`, `int` and `MPI_Comm`.

In this context, having `a` and `b` or `&a` and &b, respectively is the *"same"*. The same in the sense that `a` and `&a` yield the same memory address. Notwithstanding, there are important differences between using `a` and `&a`, for an in-depth explanation read the following [difference between “array” and “&array”](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-array-and-array-for-int-array5/).

> Array a and reduce_storage are allocated in the same way so the are of
> the same dimension m * n, the value of count argument of MPI_Reduce. I
> don't understand why I try to run it return this error:

In the second call

```
MPI_Reduce(&a, &reduce_storage, m * n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The argument `a` and `reduce_storage` are now both of type `double*` and you are passing `&a` and `&reduce_storage` as argument of the  `MPI_Reduce`. This is wrong because `&a` and `&reduce_storage` will return the address of the variable `a`, and `reduce_storage`, respectively, which would be a pointer to a pointer-to-double.

> Assuming I use p process, I need to reduce p

Side note: Using the 'p' as the total number of sizes is a little be confusion, a better name IMO would be `total_processes`, `number_of_processes` or something along those lines.